# iis7 url rewrite matching query string exactly

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7

trying to create a rule that will redirect http://www.mystore.com/product_info.php?products_id=3 to http://www.mystore.com/product/widget-666

so far I got the following:

```
            <rule name="Rewrite for .php"  stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)product_info\.php$" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="products_id=3" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)mystore*" />
                </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="/product/widget-666" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

... however it does not match exactly on products_id=3, if products_id=8 it still redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
```

to

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
```